# Centering Draggable Element in Droppable After Drop in jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

Can you take a look at **[this Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/zamk71ek/2/)** and let me know how to force draggable element to be centered inside the droppable after drop?

```
$(function () {

    $('#draggable').draggable({});
    $("#droppable").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            $(this)
                .find("p")
                .html("Dropped!");
                 $('#draggable').css("margin","2px");
        }
    });
});
```

As you can see I already  `$('#draggable').css("margin","2px");` tried but this is not doing the job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something that may give you a start - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zamk71ek/4/).

Put a hidden div inside a div onto which you wish to drop something.

Position the hidden div as you see fit.

Size the hidden div the same as your "draggable".

Make the hidden div the "droppable".

Then use "snap" and "snapTolerance" to force alignment with the edges.

JS

```
$('#draggable').draggable({
                           snap: '.hiddendiv',
                           snapTolerance: 50
                          });
$(".hiddendiv").droppable();
```

Comment: Thanks TimSPQR, just wondering if there is a way to do snapping smoother! right now it looks like there are pauses in div dragging (in frond end of course) is there any way do prevent this?

Comment: Here's a different approach - http://jsfiddle.net/zamk71ek/5/ - you can adjust the snapTolerance to your needs.

Comment: And here is yet another approach - it's a bit kludgy - but it works - http://jsfiddle.net/zamk71ek/6/